# Make slider full width, but center contents

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm playing about with http://www.slidesjs.com/ slider. Trying to make it full width, but make the current slide (slidescontent) full width, but have a div inside the container (slidescenter) have it's contents stay centered with a width set, this is the code im using:

```
<!doctype html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>

        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            .slides_container {
                width:100%;
                height:270px;
            }
            .slides_container div {
                width:100%;
                height:270px;
                display:block;
            }
           .slidescontent {width:100%;}
           .slidescenter {width:990px;}
        </style>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="slides.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("#slides").slides();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="slides">
            <div class="slides_container">
                <div class="slidescontent">
                  <div class="slidescenter">
                    Text 1
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Text 2
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/570x270">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/570x270">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle). [Slidesjs](http://www.slidesjs.com) was adding unwanted html... causing some problems

I did a centered slideshow on this site: http://celebrationsnetwork.co.nz

Did it by making the main container set width and centered (using margin)

```
#slides {
    width: 570px;
    height: 270px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And making the slides set width also:

```
#slides .slide {
    width: 570px;
    height: 270px;
}​
```

I played around with your problem on Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3q8cX/4

Any questions?

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to actually use slides.js (as it's referring to a copy on your local machine/server), it's a little hard to tell what's going on.  Have you tried to center .slidescenter the standard way?

```
.slidescenter {
  width: 990px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```